# remove duplicates values in a column seperated by comma in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to remove duplicates in a column via Pandas.
I tried `df.drop_duplicates()` but no luck.
How to achieve this in Pandas?

**Input**:

```
A
team=red, Manager=Travis
team=Blue, Manager=John, team=Blue
Manager=David, Bank=HDFC, team=XYZ, Bank=HDFC
```

**Expected_Output**:

```
A
team=red, Manager=Travis
team=Blue, Manager=John
Manager=David, Bank=HDFC, team=XYZ
```

**Code**

```
df = df.drop_duplicates('A', keep='last')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use some data structures to achieve this result.

1. split entries
2. convert to set (or some non duplicated structure)
3. join back to string

```py
print(df['A'])
0                         team=red, Manager=Travis
1               team=Blue, Manager=John, team=Blue
2    Manager=David, Bank=HDFC, team=XYZ, Bank=HDFC
Name: A, dtype: object


out = (
    df['A'].str.split(r',\s+')
    .map(set)
    .str.join(", ")
)

print(out)
0              Manager=Travis, team=red
1               team=Blue, Manager=John
2    Bank=HDFC, team=XYZ, Manager=David
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Alternatively, if the order of your string entries is important, you can use `dict.fromkeys` instead of a `set`. Since dictionaries are implicitly ordered as of Py > 3.6

```py
out = (
    df['A'].str.split(r',\s+')
    .map(dict.fromkeys)
    .str.join(", ")
)

print(out)
0              team=red, Manager=Travis
1               team=Blue, Manager=John
2    Manager=David, Bank=HDFC, team=XYZ
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df['A'].str.split(',').explode().str.strip(' ')\
       .drop_duplicates().groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
```

Output:

```
0             team=red,Manager=Travis
1              team=Blue,Manager=John
2    Manager=David,Bank=HDFC,team=XYZ
Name: A, dtype: object
```